# inserting an html tag into a html file through the command line

Tags: javascript, html, command-line

I’m developing an application that dynamically generates a new HTML page. Essentially the app takes a .zip file, uses a child process to unzip that file and inside that directory is an index.html file that my application than points to. What I need to do is insert one line of code into that index.html file, after the child process runs and generates the file. Is it possible to insert a simple  tag into the body of the index.html file through the command line? I would need the  tag to be the first line in the body of the HTML file. Any help with this is appreciated, Thanks.

```
<!-- HTML tag to insert -->
<a href="./anotherFile.html">Go Back</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a mac and you have homebrew, you can install `gnu-sed`

```sh
brew install gnu-sed
```

---

1. This will append your link **after the opening `<body>` tag**:

   ```sh
   gsed -ri '/<body>/a \  <a href=\".\/anotherFile.html\"><\/a>' your_file.html
   ```

   Here we are matching the opening body tag `/<body>/` and using the the `a` command to append text **after** the line with the match.

---

2. This will insert your link **before the closing `</body>` tag**:

   ```sh
   gsed -ri '/<\/body>/i \  <a href=\".\/anotherFile.html\"><\/a>' your_file.html
   ```

   Here we are matching the closing body tag `/<\/body>/` and using the `i` command to insert text on the line **before** the match.

---

- I used a backslash followed by two spaces to indent the link two spaces.
- If you indent by four spaces, so you can just adjust the space
  between the `\` and the beginning of the anchor tag accordingly.

---

See the [GNU-SED](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html) docs for more information on these commands.

Comment: This is great! The only question is how to get it to insert into the first line of the body, this inserts into the last line of the body. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Developing I updated my answer above. I think you want **option 1**.